# a specific sequence of coin flips eventually i.e. as number of flips goes to infinity

Tags: probability

I want a specific sequence of `k` coin flips using a 50-50 coin.

The number of flips I will "allow" is infinite i.e.

What is the probability that I will *eventually* see a specific sequence of `k` flips (like `k` 0s, `k` 1s, etc)?

**My answer**: `1*1/2^(k-1)`

The probability of getting the first flip in the desired sequence is `1.0`.
For a coin where the probability of getting a heads or tails is NOT zero, you will EVENTUALLY get a heads or EVENTUALLY get a tails i.e. the probability of the first flip in the sequence is `1.0`.

Now that we've gotten the first desired flip in the sequence, what's the probability of getting the next flip? `1/2`
And next flip? `1/2`
And ... `1/2`

So, given infinite coin flips, the probability of EVENTUALLY getting a desired sequence of `k` coin flips is `1*1/2^(k-1)` = `2*1/2^(k)`

If this is correct, notice that `1/2^k` is probability of getting a `k`-length sequence in `k` flips.
So by going from `k` flips to infinite flips, we've only doubled our chances of seeing a specific sequence of `k` flips.

**QUESTION**
Is this correct?

**BONUS**
Show this is true by taking limits: `k` length sequence after `N` flips and as `N` goes to infinity.

Comment: I’m not finding this very clear. It might be that you never get any of the flips in the desired sequence, ever. What probability space and probability measure (not to be overly formal, but we need to ground ourselves when asking questions about “infinitely many flips”) are you using?

Comment: @FShrike you are guaranteed to get the first flip eventually. It's a probability; of course it's possible you'll never get it.

Comment: I can't reconcile: "Of course it's possible you'll never get it" with: "You are guaranteed to get [it]"

Comment: @FShrike you are guaranteed to get the first flip eventually. It’s possible you will never get the entire sequence.

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, you are wrong. For instance, you seem to be saying that if you keep on flipping coins, the probability that you NEVER see two heads in a row is $\frac12$. Which of course is not true.

Comment: If the question is something like, "If you flip a fair coin an infinite number of times, what is the probability that you eventually see $k$ heads (or tails, it doesn't matter) in a row?" Then the answer is $1$, since it happens **almost surely** (a technical term). It is *possible* that it never happens, but this only occurs with probability $0$—a possibly counterintuitive observation about probability in a space with an infinite set of outcomes.

Comment: Your answer of $(1/2)^{k-1}$ seems to give the probability that the *first $k$ flips* are either all heads or all tails. In other words, it seems to neglect the possibility that after this fails (if it fails), there are still an infinite number of attempts to make.

Comment: @BrianTung yes I see that now. I would still like to see an answer that uses finite flips and takes limit as `N` goes to infinity.

Comment: You should really use MathJax to typeset your expressions. In some cases, you can simply replace your backquotes by dollar signs. In many other cases, only minor modifications are needed. So for example, `$(1/2)^{k-1}$` yields $(1/2)^{k-1}$.